# Let $V(\Bbb K),\dim V=n$ and $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ a base of $V$. Prove any $S\subseteq B, S\ne\emptyset$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

This proof was presented to me:

The set of vectors $B = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent (is a base for $V$); the only solution of the equation $$\lambda v_1+\ldots+\lambda v_n=0, \lambda_i \in K$$

is $$\lambda_1=\ldots=\lambda_n=0$$
Proof by contradiction: Suppose there is a linearly dependent subset of $m$ vectors, with $m<n$, then there are $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ not all zero, such that:
$$\alpha_1 v_1+\ldots+\alpha_n v_n=0, \alpha_i \in K$$
It follows that we could find a solution for $\lambda_{i_k}=\alpha_k$, for $1<k<n$ and for the rest of coefficients, $\lambda_j=0$.
Then, if a linearly dependent subset of $B$ exists, $B$ cannot be linearly independent.
Therefore, any non-empty subset of $B$ is linearly independent.

- What's the meaning of $\lambda_{i_k}=\alpha_k$ and $\lambda_j$ in the proof ?
- Is it necessary to justify why B is linearly independent ?
- Is this a valid proof ?

Comment: If the set is linearly _independent_, the coefficients are _unique_. You can, assume by contradiction one of the vectors can be represented as a linear combination of the rest of the vectors. However, I don't see why an arbitrary linearly independent set should necessary be a basis for $V$ as you say in the beginning. Vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ form a basis for $V\iff \operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}=V$. $\lambda_j=0$ if you assume $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}\subset\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: Only a linearly _independent_ set can be _extended to a basis_ for the whole vector space $V$. The point is, _linearly independent vectors  cannot annihilate each other_. If the contradiction confuses you, look at $(\alpha_k-\lambda_{i_k})$.

Comment: Thank you, @Cheesecake ! I was given $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a base of $V$. Is it incorrect to conclude $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly independent ?

Comment: If it was given $B$ is a _basis_, then it is linearly _independent_.

Comment: I will clarify in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof, as reported, is not really well done, albeit correct.

First, a set $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent ***if and only if*** the only solution to $\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\dots+\lambda_nv_n=0$ is $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\dots=\lambda_n=0$.

Choose a subset $\{v_{i_1},v_{i_2},\dots,v_{i_k}\}$ of $B$ and suppose
$$
\alpha_1v_{i_1}+\alpha_2v_{i_2}+\dots+\alpha_kv_{i_k}=0 \tag{*}
$$
For $1\le i_j\le n$ with $1\le j \le k$ , define
$$
\lambda_i=
\begin{cases}
  \alpha_{i_j} & \text{if }i=i_j \\[4px]
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then clearly $\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\dots+\lambda_nv_n=0$, which implies $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\dots=\lambda_n=0$ and, in particular, $\alpha_{i_1}=\alpha_{i_2}=\dots=\alpha_{i_k}=0$. QED

Basically, you rewrite the linear combination (*) by inserting the “missing vectors” with zero coefficient. This doesn't change the result of the linear combination (which is zero by assumption), but allows to apply the assumption that the full set is linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you so much, @egreg ! Could you explain what's the meaning of the double indices in $v_{i_k}$?

Comment: @F.Zer They're just some of the indices among $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, say $i_1=3,i_2=4,i_3=7$, for example. Another way to do the proof would be: without loss of generality, we can assume that the subset is $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k\}$ (because swapping around the vectors doesn't change the fact that the set is linearly independent). Suppose $\lambda_1v_1+\dots+\lambda_kv_k=0$ and define $\lambda_{k+1}=\dots=\lambda_n=0$; then $\lambda_1v_1+\dots+\lambda_kv_k+\lambda_{k+1}v_{k+1}+\lambda_nv_n=0$ and the thesis follows as before.

Comment: So, $i \in \mathbb{Z}$, how can I interpret it ? It is something like $1_1, 3_2$ ?

Comment: @F.Zer No, it's a customary notation for denoting $k$ integers to be chosen among the given ones. See edit to my previous comment.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. It's like extracting a subsequence ? When you say $i_3=7$, does it mean you are extracting 7 vectors ? If this is not correct, I don't want to bother. Could you point me to a site or book where I can learn it ?

Comment: @F.Zer I mean that the third extracted index is 7

Comment: Thank you, @egreg. I think I got it. So, when $i_3=7$, $v_{i_3}=v_{7}$. Is that correct ? Is there some rationale for extracting the indices or, it does only mean they are _arbitrary_ ?

Comment: @F.Zer The idea is that they're arbitrarily chosen, indeed.